# Making client side only POST request to 3rd party API using Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making web application with Meteor, and idea is that we have all the functionalities in client side, and client would perform API calls to our REST API. Problem is that I don't manage sent any HTTPS POST requests to our API server. Internet is full of posts that say problem is in the CORS headers, but API server sends header: access-control-allow-origin: *. So that shouldn't be the problem.

I have simple login template and for that template I will catch the submit event with this:

```
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';
import "./login.html";

Template.login.events({
   'submit .login_form'(event) {
       const target = event.target;
       let username = target.username.value;
       let password = target.password.value;

       // attempted HTTPS POST request
       // Meteor.http.post(my_api_url, { // no success with this either
       HTTP.call("POST", my_api_url, {
           data: {
               method: "login",
               params: {
                   username: username,
                   passwrd: password
               }
           }
       }, function (error, result) {
           // we will end up here just fine, but 'error' contains error
           // result is undefined 
           console.log(error);
       });
   // do stuff
   },
});
```

console.log(result) gives me this error:

```
Error: network
Stack trace:
httpcall_client.js/HTTP.call/xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:3000/packages/http.js?hash=2a49...181ea:243:20
```

And yes, i have tested the API with postman and it should return something with data shown in above. I run Meteor app in localhost.

Edit:
Json that I'm trying to pass to API is

```
{"method": "login", 
 "params": {"username": "username", 
 "passwrd": "password"}}
```

Edit 2:
When looking at the browsers network tab, I don't see any out going requests.

My Meteor template looks like this:

```
<template name="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form class="login_form" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </form>
</template>
```

Comment: And what is the value of your `my_api_url`?

Comment: It's Meteor's global variable, string. https://myurl.foo/api . cant reveal the real url

Comment: Well, ok, could you `console.log` this variable just before doing your request? So you would be sure that it's correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct :).

Comment: Well then, so what result will be for `console.debug(error)`?

Comment: same as console.log(error): "Error: network
Stack trace:
httpcall_client.js/HTTP.call/xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:3000/packages/http.js?hash=2a49...181ea:243:20"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `event.preventDefault();` line at beginning of the function

```
Template.login.events({
   'submit .login_form'(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
```

After I had prevented the client to perform POST requests to my meteor app, browser started to sent OPTIONS requests to API server. But this didn't fix the problem completely.

Then the problem was that Meteor was running in port 3000, and API server sets CORS header: access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost, leaving the port number out, and thats why all the client side requests are failing when running the Meteor app in localhost. When testing the requests with postman/cURL the access-control-allow-origin header was always set as *, which wasn't case with the browser sending the request.

Installing the lighttpd and setting it as a reverse proxy to run meteor app in port 80, and then adding new host name for the ip 127.0.0.1 in etc/hosts -file, e.g. "127.0.0.1 localhost mymeteor.app" solved my problem. Now I have to access my Meteor app in url mymeteor.app and it works.

link to configure lighttpd as proxy: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

Comment: In your question you stated that your API server has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, now — that it has `http://localhost` instead of `*`. And it has nothing to do with port, because its *origin*. If your API server has something different from `*` then you have to specify `Origin: ...` header in your request. So that issue would be solved without installing http proxy server.

Comment: If API server would accept origin that is defined in the request and it trusts it, isn't that then security issue? (at least when the request comes from browser?)

Comment: It's defined that way. Browser sends `Origin: ...` header with `OPTIONS` request and see what it receives from the API service. Based on this response browser allows (or not) your request made in javascript. It doesn't matter what port is used to acccess to API service, only _origin_ matters.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have an error on your server side.

According to the [`http` package source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/http/httpcall_client.js#L130-L132) the `network` error will be thrown (passed to callback) only if the request has been completed but there was no http answer. Thus, that's not a client issue.

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong, or shouldn't your callback be:

```
function (error, result) {
    //...
}
```

Edit: I am not wrong: Check also the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call), the example there also uses a callback in the style as shown above.

That would at least explain, why result is an error. (It does not explain why your http call returns an error itself).

Edit 2: I see more pitfalls here.

Look at the `options` object structure:

```
{
    method: "POST",
    params: {
        username: username,
        passwrd: password
    }
}
```

Could also be:

```
{
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        username: username,
        passwrd: password
    }
}
```

Depending on you web service requirements. Then there is a point regarding `password` - is this intended or a typo?

Then what about using `auth`

```
{
    method: "POST",
    params: { // or data...?
        username: username,
        passwrd: password
    },
    auth: username+":"+password
}
```

It seems rather a configuration issue, depending on the requirements of your web service. Try different option configurations. There must be a solution.

Can you add the line of how you call the web service manually?

Comment: I have tried that also, in this case result is undefined and error contains the error

Comment: Which is correct behavior then, because on error the callback should contain an undefined result parameter and the error stored in the error parameter. On result, the callback should contain an undefined error and the result in result.

Comment: Correct behavior yes, but doesn't explain why i can't make the POST request?

Comment: Are `username` and `password` not empty and valid credentials for a login?

Comment: both variables contain something, in case of incorrect credentials API should return also HTTP 200 and json with error message. with success it also returns HTTP 200 and user information

Comment: I modified the original post to contain the json that i'm trying to pass to API

Comment: when reading the doc more carefully i seems i have to add json inside data: {}. But still I will get the same error. What do you mean by calling web service manually? I'm using webStorm to run my Meteor app.